# Insert One to One field value in django

Tags: django, forms

I have the following models.

```
class PatientInfo(models.Model):
    lastname = models.CharField('Last Name', max_length=200)
    firstname = models.CharField('First Name',max_length=200)
    middlename = models.CharField('Middle Name',max_length=200)
    ...
    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('patient:medical-add', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class MedicalHistory(models.Model):
    patient = models.OneToOneField(PatientInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True,)
    ...
```

and upon submitting PatientInfo form it will go to another form which supply the MedicalHistory Details. I can see my PatientInfo data as well as MedicalHistory data but not linked to each other. Below is my MedicalCreateView which process my MedicalHistory form.

```
class MedicalCreateView(CreateView):

    template_name = 'patient/medical_create.html'
    model = MedicalHistory
    form_class = MedicalForm

    def post(self, request, pk):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)


        if form.is_valid():
            patiente = form.save(commit=False)
            physician_name = form.cleaned_data['physician_name'] # do not delete
            patient = PatientInfo.objects.all(id=self.kwargs['pk'])

            MedicalHistory.patient = self.kwargs['pk']


            patiente.save()
            messages.success(request, "%s is added to patient list" % physician_name )

            return redirect('index')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
```

This is how I set MedicalHistory.patient field using the PatientInfo.pk

```
MedicalHistory.patient = self.kwargs['pk']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `OneToOneField` and want to link `MedicalHistory` to `PatientInfo` automatically you need to use `signals`.

```
class MedicalHistory(models.Model):
    patient = models.OneToOneField(PatientInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True,)
    . . . . . 

@receiver(post_save, sender=PatientInfo)
def create_medical_history(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        MedicalHistory.objects.create(patient=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=PatientInfo)
def save_medical_history(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.medicalhistory.save()
```

**Views**

```
class MedicalCreateView(CreateView):

    template_name = 'patient/medical_create.html'
    model = MedicalHistory
    form_class = MedicalForm
    success_url = '/'
```

Comment: should I remove my form.is_valid form and use return redirect('index') instead? how should I call created_medical history and save_medical_history in my form. Thank you for your response.

Comment: first submit throws error like this, UNIQUE constraint failed: patient_medicalhistory.patient_id. Then when I hit refresh it proceeds to my medicalhistory form. When I filled in the form and submit again it shows two records from the same input, still no connection between PatientInfo and MedicalHistory.

Comment: After creating OneToOne field you need to format the database so that only 1 is matched.

Comment: okay I fixed the relationship issue by addming patient = models.OneToOneField(PatientInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, unique=False) in my model MedicalHistory. My problem now it recorded two Medical history, one is the physician_name and one is the patient only . Any suggestions?

Comment: any recommedation?