# Django Signals and form is_valid

Tags: django, signals

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46415194/insert-one-to-one-field-value-in-django). I would like to save my form data in relation to the created signal:

Model :

```
  class PatientInfo(models.Model):
     lastname = models.CharField('Last Name', max_length=200)
     ...

  class MedicalHistory(models.Model):
    patient = models.OneToOneField(PatientInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    physician_name = models.CharField('Physician', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    ...

  @receiver(post_save, sender=PatientInfo)
  def create_medical_history(sender, **kwargs):
     if kwargs.get('created', False):
     MedicalHistory.objects.create(patient=kwargs.get('instance'))
```

View

```
class MedicalCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'patient/medical_create.html'
    model = MedicalHistory
    form_class = MedicalForm
    success_url = '/'

    def post(self, request, pk):
      form = self.form_class(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
        patiente = form.save(commit=False)
        physician_name = form.cleaned_data['physician_name'] # do not delete
        patiente.save()
        messages.success(request, "%s is added to patient list" % physician_name )
        return redirect('index')
      else:
        print(form.errors)
```

My code above saves two entry in my MedicalHistory table, patient field is linked to Patient_info.id while the other is empty yet populated with form data.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my `MedicalHistory` model is has generated its its own automatically, based in my `PatientInfo` . My way of populating data to existing `MedicalHistory`id is by changing:

```
class MedicalCreateView(CreateView)
```

to

```
class MedicalCreateView(UpdateView):
```

I removed this

```
def post(self, request, pk):

  form = self.form_class(request.POST)
   if form.is_valid():
     patiente = form.save(commit=False)
     physician_name = form.cleaned_data['physician_name'] # do not delete
     patiente.save()
     messages.success(request, "%s is added to patient list" % physician_name )
     return redirect('index')
   else:
     print(form.errors)
```